# Background Download gets stuck after one set of videos in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am stuck in one issue where I need to download around 1500 videos in the background. These videos have been put under different categories and all the categories are shown as a list.
Whichever list-item the user chooses, all the videos will be downloaded under that category. User may choose all the categories also to download at one go. There is a requirement to download one category after another, that means the download sequence should follow the order of user selection.

We are using NSURLSession with background configuration. We are able to achieve all the above functionalities when the app is in the foreground. When the app goes to background, the next category video-set is not fired. What I observed is: we are not able to add additional download tasks to the session in the background. Please let us know if this is a limitation from iOS side or we can have any work around. We tried with Background Fetch also along with session, but that is not triggered in a dedicated way, as that is a periodical scenario.

No documentation found on: Firing additional download tasks in the session call back delegates, when in background. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

when app goes in background..new download can't start... only previous download which is running can be done in background... and also this download time is set by apple to 3-5 min depending on data type download... which can exceed to 10 min after requesting specially for some data download.

so you can't download videos in background while app is not in foreGround state... instead of this just download video thumnails.... and show them to user... when user taps on a video.. then start their download.... Also note that according to apple term and policies apple reject those application which download very huge amount of data which in your case true....because you are trying to download 1500 videos... which will use very huge amount of data

Comment: Thanks Divyanshu,  but I am able to fire around 50 requests at one go in the foreground which takes around an hour to complete, there is no issue I see. Only issue I am seeing is when I am trying to fire another set of urls inside the background delegate callback method.

Comment: because Sir this app is not live... once you send it to app store all apple terms and policies works for it.... which says your download can't exceed more than 3-5 minutes.

Comment: Ok, can you please send the apple policy link for this or any other relevant  link, which describes this clause that would be helpful, Thanks for the quick responses

Comment: Regarding Apple's guidelines against excessive downloads, I believe that only applies to apps that download excessive data over cellular.

Comment: Hey Manhalli...Please check this link... this link have important information about your task... may be this can help you  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html